# Disk usage inside archives, like ncdu

Tags: software-rec, disk-usage, compression, ncurses

I am a fond user of the [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) utility to figure out how space is used within a directory.

However, I have a use case where I am trying to choose which folders to backup and which folders not to backup, and the backups will be compressed (as a .tar.xz archive, but I suppose .tar.gz would yield the same result for what I have in mind). So, intuitively, I do not care that much about files that are large but will compress well (e.g., email archives), whereas I care more about files that are relatively small but will not compress at all (e.g., JPG pictures). I want to see files and folders sorted by their compressed size, not their actual uncompressed size.

A natural solution would be to compress all files, and then have an `ncdu`-like tool that would operate *on the archive* to tell me how folders take up space in the archive.

Is there any such utility?

I am OK with GUI programs (although I would prefer text-based ones), and I am OK with methods that would only work for a different compression algorithm as I imagine they would still yield useful results (e.g., replicate the hierarchy in a filesystem with built-in compression/deduplication).

Comment: Interesting. Never heard of ncdu before, but it seems really handy.

Comment: ncdu is great!  Thank you from September 2017 (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ncdu` itself!

This shows the uncompressed sizes of the files.
In the case you say you care about, namely many uncompressible files, it should reflect what you need pretty well:

To make the file sizes **accessible** to `ncdu`, they need to be **in a file system**. So we need to mount the archive as a file system.

We use a **fuse user-space filesystem** implementation, [`archivemount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/archivemount.1.html):

Install the fuse file system:

```
sudo apt-get install archivemount
```

`mkdir` a directory, `mount` the archive to it, `cd` into it, and run `ncdu`:

```
$ mkdir bash-4.3-mount
$ archivemount bash-4.3.tar.gz bash-4.3-mount
$ cd bash-4.3-mount
$ ncdu
```

Now you can use `ncdu` just normally:

```
ncdu 1.10 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help                     
--- /tmp/archivedutest/bash-4.3-mount/bash-4.3/lib ----------------
                        /..                                                      
    1.2MiB [##########] /readline
  343.0KiB [##        ] /sh
  316.5KiB [##        ] /intl
  104.5KiB [          ] /glob
   97.0KiB [          ] /malloc
   32.0KiB [          ] /termcap
   22.0KiB [          ] /tilde

 Total disk usage:   2.1MiB  Apparent size:   2.0MiB  Items: 251
```

---

Now, what you are really interested in is the compressed size of the files, not uncompressed: You want to see which files take up the most space in the actual archive.

Strictly speaking, that's not possible because the archive is compressed as a whole. An individual file has no "compressed size".

So the compressed size of individual files can only be approximated.
One approximation would be the size of individually compressed files.
Another would be a fraction of the compressed size assuming all files compress by the same ratio. There are certainly other ways.

The first seems to be ok. To implement it, there is no way around actually unpacking and recompressing the individual files, so I see no reason to not just do that, unpack to the filesystem, and use ncdu on the files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is a good idea, but what I care about is the *compressed* size of the files, not uncompressed: I want to see which files take up the most space in the actual archive. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's not possible because the archive is compressed as a whole. An individual file has no "compressed size".

Comment: So it can only be approximated. One approximation would be the size of individually compressed files. Another would be a fraction of the compressed size assuming all files compress by the same ratio. There are certainly other ways. The first seems to be ok. To implement it, there is no way around actually unpacking and recompressing the individual files, so I see no reason to not just do that, and use `ncdu` on it.

Comment: For `gzip`, I think that decompression can be done in streaming, and `tar` archives are sequential, so one should be able to talk of the compressed size of a file as the difference between the offset of this file and the offset of the next file, no? (I don't know gzip in detail so I may be missing some subtleties.) Of course this would favor files that come later in the archive (e.g., if I have two copies of the same file, only the first would take space) but I guess that's an OK approximation. What do you think?

Comment: Sure, that could be done in memory, but I do not see much reason for that - using the filesystem is essentially the same using standard tools. You can use a `tmpfs` to write to if you insist in using memmory, of course. Regarding using the stream offsets for sizes, I can not easily picture it, but expect that it will not work in general,  based on the compressed-as-a-whole issue. Would be worth some experiments...

Comment: This is really good.   Thank you from September 2017 (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).